# Pig's AvroStorage LOAD removes unicode chars from input

Tags: unicode, apache-pig, avro

I am using pig to read avro files and normalize/transform the data before writing back out. The avro files have records of the form:

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "KeyValuePair",
  "namespace" : "org.apache.avro.mapreduce",
  "doc" : "A key/value pair",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "key",
    "type" : "string",
    "doc" : "The key"
  }, {
    "name" : "value",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "map",
      "values" : "bytes"
    },
    "doc" : "The value"
  } ]
}
```

I have used the AvroTools [command-line utility](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2013/03/17/reading-and-writing-avro-files-from-the-command-line/) in conjunction with [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to dump the first record to JSON:

```
    $ java -jar avro-tools-1.8.1.jar tojson part-m-00000.avro | ./jq --compact-output 'select(.value.pf_v != null)' | head -n 1 | ./jq .
{
  "key": "some-record-uuid",
  "value": {
    "pf_v": "v1\u0003Basic\u0001slcvdr1rw\u001a\u0004v2\u0003DayWatch\u0001slcva2omi\u001a\u0004v3\u0003Performance\u0001slc1vs1v1w1p1g1i\u0004v4\u0003Fundamentals\u0001snlj1erwi\u001a\u0004v5\u0003My Portfolio\u0001svr1dews1b2b3k1k2\u001a\u0004v0\u00035"
  }
}
```

I run the following pig commands:

```
REGISTER avro-1.8.1.jar
REGISTER json-simple-1.1.1.jar
REGISTER piggybank-0.15.0.jar
REGISTER jackson-core-2.8.6.jar
REGISTER jackson-databind-2.8.6.jar

DEFINE AvroLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
AllRecords = LOAD 'part-m-00000.avro'
    USING AvroLoader()
    AS (key: chararray, value: map[]);

Records = FILTER AllRecords BY value#'pf_v' is not null;

SmallRecords = LIMIT Records 10;
DUMP SmallRecords;
```

The corresponding record for the last command above is as follows:

```
...
(some-record-uuid,[pf_v#v03v1Basicslcviv2DayWatchslcva2omiv3Performanceslc1vs1v1w1p1g1i])
...
```

As you can see the unicode chars have been removed from the `pf_v` value. The unicode characters are actually being used as delimiters in these values so I will need them in order to fully parse the records into their desired normalized state. The unicode characters are clearly present in the encoded `.avro` file (as demonstrated by dumping the file to JSON). Is anybody aware of a way to get AvroStorage to **not** remove the unicode chars when loading records?

Thank you!

**Update:**
I have also performed the **same** operation using Avro's python DataFileReader:

```
import avro.schema
from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

reader = DataFileReader(open("part-m-00000.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())

for rec in reader:
    if 'some-record-uuid' in rec['key']:
        print rec
        print '--------------------------------------------'
        break

reader.close()
```

This prints a dict with what looks like hex chars substituted for the unicode chars (which is preferable to removing them entirely):

```
{u'value': {u'pf_v': 'v0\x033\x04v1\x03Basic\x01slcvi\x1a\x04v2\x03DayWatch\x01slcva2omi\x1a\x04v3\x03Performance\x01slc1vs1v1w1p1g1i\x1a'}, u'key': u'some-record-uuid'}
```